# WYSIWYG browser editor that generates *good* HTML?

Tags: html, editor, wysiwyg

I'm searching for a "suck less" WYSIWYG *in*-browser X?HTML editor that generates **good** HTML code.

(no `<font>`, `<foo style="...">`, `<p></p><span></span><p><span>&nbsp;</span><span><span>blah</span></<span></p>` and so on -- `<b>` and `<i>` etc is ok).

Should be easy-to-use as it is going to be used by people that do not know what HTML is.

**Any suggestions?**

Extra points for Copy-and-Paste-from-Word-readiness! :-)

(I found a lot of editors but they all create that `<font>` and nested `<span>` crap that breaks site design and bloats a site with one table up to 100kB.)

Comment: You can't never go wrong with notepad.

Comment: Haha aren't we all looking for that? I was recently working on redoing a small town's community website that was done with a reeeally old version of frontpage. It was full of things like triple nested font tags and divs with id's like AAB3239F...What we really need is a WYSIWYG editor that uses css correctly instead of tables and garbage tags!

Comment: By "WYSIWYG browser HTML editor" do you mean an editor that can be used inside a browser? Or are you looking for a desktop solution?

Comment: Chris, I wouldn't have used the word "browser" in that phrase if I meant a desktop solution. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Download the current version of [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and look at the XHTML output sample. It shows how to use full WYSIWYG but it doesn't generates font or styles. You just need to adjust the configuration to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

What about [WYMEditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/)?

> WYMeditor has been created to generate perfectly structured XHTML strict code, to conform to the W3C XHTML specifications and to facilitate further processing by modern applications.
>
> With WYMeditor, the code can't be contaminated by visual informations like font styles and weights, borders, colors, ... The end-user defines content meaning, which will determine its aspect by the use of style sheets. The result is easy and quick maintenance of information.

I've used it a little and while it takes quite a bit of tweaking if you have very specific needs, it does work out of the box for simple XHTML editing. If you set up specially annotated CSS files then it will detect the styles you want users to use and block level elements to which they apply. You can also tell it how to display these styles in the editor (which might be different from how you want them displayed in the resulting XHTML).

Of course, it generates **XHTML**, not HTML, so it may not meet your exact needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Markdown with the WMD UI](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/), it's the one used by Stack Overflow. It always produces valid HTML code.

Comment: WMD UI seems to be defunct.  Website gives 404.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has a category for them:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:JavaScript-based_HTML_editors

Answer (score 1):

I just recently searched for an editor to create solid documentation, whose output is suitable for Subversion diffs: https://superuser.com/questions/126621/wysiwyg-editor-for-structured-text-suitable-for-svn-versioning

The editor that was suggested - ["KompoZer"](http://www.kompozer.net/) - turned out to be fantastic, especially because it generates very clean HTML (in my opinion). And I say that, although I had originally preferred something leaner than HTML.

P.S. Reading your question again, I'm not sure, what you mean with a "browser editor" - are you looking for an editor that can be integrated in an HTML page? KompoZer is based on a browser, but it can probably not be integrated in an HTML page.

Comment: KompoZer is not great, but it is the best [free] WYSIWYG HTML editor I have found, too.

Comment: Thanks, but that's a desktop client, I'm searching for an in-browser editor. Apparently that wasn't phrased clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I recently switched one of my projects to markdown to avoid this exact issue. There's still a bit of a learning curve for the users but I haven't had to deal with the usual issues that occur when they copy/paste content from Word and wonder why it blew up.

Having said that, I prefer [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) over TinyMCE and the Telerik controls. I've generally found it generates somewhat cleaner HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There are several WYSIWG editors for embedding within your website out there.

WYMeditor (http://www.wymeditor.org/) looks very nice and seems to be a good fit for targetting clean and valid XHTML results.

Answer (score 0):

[Spaw2](http://www.spaweditor.com/). Although it's kinda abandoned now.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple Cocoa NSTextView class exports quite nice html, where all the fiddling is done through specifying a style sheet in the header.  The Apple TextEdit editor uses this.

Answer (score 0):

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/ - easy to use, can import form Word, and restrict formatting to predefined CSS styles, to provide consistent output.

Comment: Sloooow and creates awful Javascript after few edits. Breaks everything if stupid people Copy and Paste from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This post is 8+ years old now but still relevant...

I found an [awesome github page](https://github.com/JefMari/awesome-wysiwyg) with a curated list of WYSIWYG editors, including a few WYSIWYM ones which guarantee sane html. As of 2018, the most current and best WYSIWYM one looks like [ProseMirror](https://github.com/ProseMirror/prosemirror), or maybe [ORY Editor](https://github.com/ory/editor) if you're looking for something to edit entire webpages(!) in one textfield.